# JSF 2.0 application : javax.servlet not found

Tags: java, jsf

I'm developing a simple login/logout application with JSF 2.0, GlassFish 3, Eclipse IDE. For some reason I need to implement a *filter*.

When I'm trying to import the necessary classes I get the following eclipse error:

```
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved
```

I was under the impression that javax packages are included in JDK.

*Note:* I created a new project without the JSF settings and the import works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javax.servlet.* is part of the Java **EE** SDK. You need to add servlet-api.jar to the build path of your Eclipse project. I would imagine you can find it in one of the Glassfish directories.

Edit: The accepted answer to [Tomcat 6 conversion to Glassfish v3: servlet-api, el-api jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913444/tomcat-6-conversion-to-glassfish-v3-servlet-api-el-api-jars) contains better advice then I have just given you above!

Comment: Should I configure some path to the Glassfish directory containing the import or is it OK to just paste the jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Please see the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913444/tomcat-6-conversion-to-glassfish-v3-servlet-api-el-api-jars - definitely don't paste it into WEB-INF/lib. If you do that and deploy it on something other than Glassfish (or possibly on a different version of Glassfish) you may see some conflicts. (Each server will include its own specific implementation of servlet-api.jar)