# GlassFish 3.1.2 gives 404 without any error on deployment

Tags: deployment, glassfish, http-status-code-404, war

I try to deploy a realy simple helloworld.war to a glassfish 3.1.2 server on ubuntu 10.04. On my PC it works fine but on my server I get always a 404 page.
I get no errors on my server. Has anyone an idea?

I noticed another strange behavior. After a reboot of my server I can't login to the admin console. I get always Authentication Failed Re-enter your username and password. When I restart glassfish it works again.

This sounds familiar but I don't see how his solution can help me.
[glassfish autodeploy gives 404 with simple app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908782/glassfish-autodeploy-gives-404-with-simple-app)

```
[#|2012-12-14T02:53:30.368+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=71;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war|#]

[#|2012-12-14T02:53:30.605+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=135;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) für Kontext '/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT' wird initialisiert.|#]

[#|2012-12-14T02:53:30.729+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=135;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0671: Loading application [HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT] at [/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]|#]

[#|2012-12-14T02:53:30.883+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=135;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT was successfully deployed in 482 milliseconds.|#]
```

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
    </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have the index.xhtml in a dir called faces...try this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: ok..I noticed it would work anyway...which url are you calling?

Comment: over Application -> Lunch it gives me IP:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT

But I have tried IP:8080/HelloWorld too.

Comment: @user1902794 I am facing the same error did you  find the solution?

Comment: @Sanshai28 No not really. I can’t reproduce it anymore. The server setup changed and the error was gone. Right now I'm using GlassFish 4 in a docker container with the latest oracle java version.